# Solving $\Box u=0$ in an open set with $u(p)$ and $\mathrm{grad}\, u(p)$ prescribed

Tags: differential-geometry, partial-differential-equations, riemannian-geometry, general-relativity

Consider a $C^k$, $k\ge 2$, Lorentzian manifold $(M,g)$ and let $\Box$ be the usual wave operator $\nabla^a\nabla_a$. Given $p\in M$, $s\in\Bbb R,$ and $v\in T_pM$, can we find a neighborhood $U$ of $p$ and $u\in C^k(U)$ such that $\Box u=0$, $u(p)=s$ and $\mathrm{grad}\, u(p)=v$?

Comment: Would [math.se] be  a better home for this question?

Comment: You want to specify data at a single point only?  Seems unlikely that this problem is well-posed - the classical theory (see e.g. Hormander, Taylor, John's PDE books)  says data must be specified on a noncharacteristic ("space-like") submanifold.  It's been a year or two since I've read this stuff otherwise I would answer more completely.

Comment: @icurays1 I am not looking for uniqueness, I just want *some* solution to exist with those properties.

Comment: The standard existence theory @icurays1 mentions should specialize: pick nice coordinates near $p$ and prescribe $u, \partial_t u$ on some patch of $\{t = t(p)\}$, which in particular lets you choose $u(p), \nabla u(p).$

Comment: @AnthonyCarapetis Right, that was my idea. But there's some technical issues with solving the equation backwards in time and forwards, then matching up the solutions smoothly. That can probably be fixed, but I'm hoping there's a simpler solution.

Comment: Yeah, I agree that there should be an easier way. In the flat case we can simply write down a linear function, and I suspect that if the metric is analytic near $p$ there should be an appropriate analytic $u$ with coefficients determined by $s,v$ and the coefficients of the metric. In general I guess one could try a perturbation argument - e.g. apply the [method of continuity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_of_continuity) on some appropriate local space of functions to interpolate between the flat case and the desired metric.